# Socket: How does connect/accept use the 3-way handshake, if they ever do?

Tags: sockets

I have a TCP server and multiple clients attempting to connect to that server almost simultaneously. I notice that:

1. On the client side, `connect` may return 0 even though the 3-way handshake has not been completed yet.
2. On the server side, `accept` may not return even after the 3-way handshake has been completed.

To illustrate both points, here are the Wireshark traces (server is listening on port 1234):

**1. Here are the Wireshark traces for the case where client's `connect` returns 0 even though the 3-way handshake has not been completed (missing last SYN from client):**

```
// calls ::connect ...
59507 → 1234 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
1234 → 59507 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
// ... and ::connect returned 0, despite the above 2 lines 
// forming an incomplete handshake. Why?

// after the ::connect, client calls ::send to send 8 bytes ...
59507 → 1234 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262656 Len=8

// ... but we got reset by peer
1234 → 59507 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0

// ... and as expected, ::send returned 10054 (WSAECONNRESET)
```

**2. Server's `accept` doesn't return even after the 3-way handshake has been completed:**

```
// server calls ::accept ...
59643 → 1234 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
1234 → 59643 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
59643 → 1234 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=262656 Len=0
// At this point, we have a complete handshake, but server's ::accept doesn't return. Why?

// In the next line, server sends a RST. This doesn't cause the server's ::accept call 
// to return an INVALID_SOCKET, which doesn't seem unreasonable (since nothing is accepted), 
// nor is this the point of the question, but I am including the RST trace here 
// for completeness. The main point is that it's as if server's ::accept is oblivious 
// to the successful handshake.
1234 → 59643 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

**Questions:**

1. When, exactly, does `connect` return? Apparently the traces above suggests that `connect` can return (and declare success with return value of 0) even if the handshake is incomplete.
2. When, exactly, does `accept` return? The traces above suggests that the completion of a 3-way handshake isn't good enough for `accept` to return, which is puzzling.

So, it's as if `connect` doesn't care about checking the handshake, while `accept` is so strict that a successful handshake is not good enough for it to return?

Comment: "connect may return 0 even though the 3-way handshake has not been completed yet."-- Though this might look like a possibility because of piggybacked TCP segments. But I don't know how apt it is to conclude it from the Wireshark traces. Your program and Wireshark are two things running independently, Wireshark may report the events later...

Comment: @MohithReddy I think it doesn't matter if Wireshark reports events later, as long as: 1) Wireshark doesn't lose events and also keeps the integrity of the order of those events, and 2) The server/client codes correctly log the return values of the accept and connect calls. With these 2 in place, we can exactly map the behaviour of the socket API calls in the server and client, to the Wireshark traces, isn't that the case?

Comment: In the case you showcased, it is conclusive that ``connect`` returned after the first two steps because the ``ACK`` is piggybacked with application data of length ``8``. But in a traces where the ``ACK`` is only sent, I believe there is a race condition between ``connect`` returning and Wireshark logging.

Comment: Neither 1 nor 2 seems likely. Are you using Wireshark's "Follow TCP Stream" command? There is typically so much other traffic on the wire that sometimes finding the traffic you're interested in can be difficult. Of course Wireshark (and the interface it is capturing on) has it's own limitations and is not guaranteed to see all the traffic that the endpoints see.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes I am isolating individual streams with "Follow TCP Stream". Anyway, I think there is a reasonable explanation for all that's going on: As I understand now, but with no authoritative source to cite yet, is that ```accept``` does not examine the handshake at all. ```listen``` alone is enough to cause the kernel's TCP stack to start accepting connections. When there is an incoming ```connect```, the kernel examines the handshake, and if complete, puts it into a queue for ```accept``` to pick up. So ```accept``` doesn't care about the handshake. The TCP stack does.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk ```accept``` returns when it picks one of those items from the queue. But more questions arise: When does ```accept``` return INVALID_SOCKET, since picking up things from a queue seem straightforward and not subject to error? If the queue is full (max size determined by ```listen```'s 2nd param) then does TCP stack on server side send a RST to the client? As for ```connect```, now I think actually it doesn't care about the handshake as well. Probably not the userspace socket API's job to do that, inferring from ```accept```'s behaviour. Anyway ... awaiting more responses.

Comment: @MohithReddy @President In case you are interested: Look at ```tcp_v4_connect``` inside https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c and drill into ```tcp_connect``` in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c: ```connect``` indeed returns without having to wait for the full handshake. As long as the 1st SYN is sent, ```connect``` returns 0. As for ```accept```, look at ```inet_csk_accept``` inside https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c: It seems to wait for full handshake. My doubts are clearing!

Comment: @moog I remember it reading from the textbook, The second argument to ``listen`` indeed sets the stack size, but it shouldn't be considered as a linear mapping (mapping various from system to system). The kernel maintains three stacks or so, for each step completing it promotes that particular connection to higher stack with ``accept`` stack being the last. So yes, ``accept`` wont manage the TCP handshake, but it is probable for accept returning INVALID_SOCKET (if the file descriptor is not socket at the first place). in the case of Linux, if stack fills syns are ignored, so client retries

Comment: @MohithReddy When you say stack size, what stack are you talking about? Stack of what items? As I understand, the 2nd param is the backlog size - a queue which stores connections. When you say "shouldn't be considered as a linear mapping" - what mapping are you talking about? A mapping of what to what? "Promotes that particular connection to a higher stack" - what is this "stack" you are talking about?

Comment: @moog Queue is the correct term. A queue of connections. The mapping between the backlog parameter and queue size, refer to this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMnkw.png). For the ``connect`` and ``accept`` return and for the queue promotion, refer to this [text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKqmI.png). For the TCP behavior when Queue size is full, refer to this [text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoFrP.png)

Answer (score 6):

So to answer the question,

- **When does `connect()` and `accept()` return?**

[image]

I am quoting from the source "Unix Network Programming" -- By W. Richard Stevens. The `connect()` returns after the first two steps of the handshake. While the `accept()` returns when an entry is placed in the `completed queue`. The meaning of queues are given as:

When the client requests a TCP connection, the server's TCP stack creates an entry in the `incomplete queue`, then the 3-way TCP handshake is managed by the server TCP stack. The connection is moved from the `incomplete queue` to the `completed queue` when the last message of the TCP handshake arrives (ACK or PiggyBacked ACK).

**For other questions raised in the comments:**

- **How does the `backlog` (2nd parameter of the `listen()`) affect the queue size?**

`backlog` is not equal to the queue size, the queue size set by the `backlog` varies from system to system. Below table lists the `backlog` and corresponding queue values for some systems:

[image]

- **What does the server do when it gets SYN, and the queue is full?**

If the queues are full when a client SYN arrives, TCP ignores the arriving SYN (pp. 930-931 0f TCPv2); it does not send an RST. Because the condition is considered temporary, and the client may retry after sometime, hoping to find the place in the queue. If instead RST is sent, then it is ambiguous whether the server queues are full or the server is not listening on that port.

Comment: Windows does send the RST. Stevens is describing the BSD behaviour, which makes far more sense.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne He do mentioned that some implementations send ``RST``, which is not the correct behaviour. I should have guessed that implementation is Windows :) Thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: @MohithReddy The mystery remains on the 2nd case I quoted, i.e. "Server's accept doesn't return even after the 3-way handshake has been completed: " though.

Comment: @moog That doesn't seem to be likely (- -) Did you cross check? Because the notion of the server is flexible, the server might be the one which sends the first byte, so it has to return immediately after a 3 way handshake.

Comment: @MohithReddy Yes, it's not a complex scenario so I am very sure of both the application and Wireshark traces. Steven's quote that "If the queues are full when a client SYN arrives, TCP ignores the arriving SYN", then the 2nd case's handshake shouldn't have been formed, because the server side would have ignored the arriving SYN and the handshake formation would have stopped right there. Perhaps Windows' behaviour is different, but it seems Windows' socket API mechanics is not well documented (if at all, since it's proprietary) and may deviate from BSD's.

Comment: @moog If I may ask, What is causing the server to send RST immediately after a 3-way handshake? I am suspecting a firewall presence! May be the last ACK which appeared on wire never reached the kernel's TCP stack because of firewall intervention....

Comment: The firewall was off. I think what *might* have happened was, that the detection of a full handshake and the storage of the connection into the Accept Queue wasn't atomic (I think it's quite reasonable to assume that it's not). So, it might have been that the Accept Queue has one slot left, and among > 1 contending fully formed handshakes, only one gets to the Accept Queue. It's not a corrupting data race per-se, just merely a "one winner" situation. Anyway, just pure speculation. But I don't know *what* caused the server's RST - @Marquis explanation seems most likely.